# Excluir linhas com determinadas condições (R)

Tags: r, dataframe

Tenho um dataframe com as seguintes linhas e variáveis:

```
| Cidade.estado                  | Cultura.de.produção |
| ------------------------------ | --------------------|
| Alta Floresta D'oeste - RO     | Agave, sisal (fibra)|
| Alta Floresta D'oeste - RO     | Açaí (fruto)        |
| Alta Floresta D'oeste - RO     | Agave, sisal (folha)|
| Alta Floresta D'oeste - RO     | Acerola             |
```

Gostaria de efetuar a exclusão de todas as linhas que são "Agave, sisal (fibra)" e "Agave, sisal (folha)"

Fiz assim:

```
DbTeste1 <- data.frame(DbNovo[DbGeral$`Cultura de produção` != "Agave, sisal (fibra)",])
```

Excluiu certo, mas quando fui fazer o processo seguinte de excluir as demais, deixou o dataframe zerado.

Usei o seguinte código em seguida:

```
DbTeste1 <- data.frame(DbTeste1[DbTeste1$`Cultura de produção` != "Agave, sisal (folha)",])
```

Comment: Ola @Murilo, Bem vindo ao [pt.so], para entender melhor o funcionamento do site vale apena dar uma olhada em nosso [Tour]. Agora especificamente sobre sua pergunta, como ela é sobre [tag:r], deixo um link que pode ajuda-lo a melhora-la e dessa forma ajudar a comunidade a entender melhor sua duvida -  [Como criar um exemplo mínimo reproduzível em R](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/825/3774)

Comment: Como estao definidos DbNovo e DbGeral?

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro vou gerar o `data.frame` com os dados que você colocou:

```
DbNovo <- data.frame(`Cidade estado` = c("Alta Floresta D'oeste - RO", "Alta Floresta D'oeste - RO", "Alta Floresta D'oeste - RO", "Alta Floresta D'oeste - RO"),
                       `Cultura de produção` = c("Agave, sisal (fibra)", "Açaí (fruto)", "Agave, sisal (folha)", "Acerola"))
```

Agora você pode fazer isso:

```
DbTeste1 <- DbNovo[!(DbNovo$`Cultura de produção` %in% c("Agave, sisal (fibra)", "Agave, sisal (folha)")), ]
```

O que esse código faz é verificar na coluna `Cultura de produção` quais as linhas que são "Agave, sisal (fibra)" ou "Agave, sisal (folha)". O "!" transforma os `True` em `False` dropando essas linhas. O `%in%` verifica quais linhas satisfazem o critério. Aqui estou usando a vetorização do [r](/questions/tagged/r).

Answer (score -1):

Como as linhas a serem removidas partilham um padrão, `"Agape, sisal"`, pode usar uma regex para as detetar com `grepl` e a seguir removê-las negando o índice lógico do `grepl`.

```r
i <- grepl("Agave, sisal", DbNovo$`Cultura de produção`)
i
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

DbNovo[!i,]
#>                Cidade estado Cultura de produção
#> 2 Alta Floresta D'oeste - RO        Açaí (fruto)
#> 4 Alta Floresta D'oeste - RO             Acerola
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Dados em formato `dput`

```r
DbNovo <-
  structure(list(
    `Cidade estado` = c("Alta Floresta D'oeste - RO", "Alta Floresta D'oeste - RO", 
                        "Alta Floresta D'oeste - RO", "Alta Floresta D'oeste - RO"), 
    `Cultura de produção` = c("Agave, sisal (fibra)", "Açaí (fruto)", 
                              "Agave, sisal (folha)", "Acerola")), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score -2):

Algum problema em apagar os dois ao mesmo tempo?

Segue abaixo um caminho:

### Criando dataframe de teste

```
DbTeste <- data.frame(Cidade = c("Alta Floresta D'oeste - RO", "Alta Floresta D'oeste - RO", "Alta Floresta D'oeste - RO", "Alta Floresta D'oeste - RO"), Cultura = c("Agave, sisal (fibra)", "Açaí (fruto)", "Agave, sisal (folha)", "Acerola"))
```

### Usando dplyr para criar novodb sem os itens que contem Agave

```
dbnovo <- DbTeste %>% filter(!grepl('Agave', Cultura))
```

### Resultado

```
dbnovo
                      Cidade      Cultura
1 Alta Floresta D'oeste - RO Açaí (fruto)
2 Alta Floresta D'oeste - RO      Acerola
```

Comment: Qual o problema com esta resposta. Para quem votou negativo, poderia dizer o motivo para que eu possa melhorar a resposta?